# Sound recording in iOS7 by AudioQueueStart function

Tags: iphone, audio, ios7, recording

My code was working fine on iOS6 but not in iOS 7 , please guide

```
UInt32 enableMetering = 0;
    status = AudioQueueSetProperty(recordState.queue, kAudioQueueProperty_EnableLevelMetering, &enableMetering,sizeof(enableMetering));
    if (status) {fprintf(stderr, "Could not enable metering\n"); return NO;}

// this line giving error
**status = AudioQueueStart(recordState.queue, NULL);**
  if (status) {fprintf(stderr, "Could not start Audio Queue\n"); return NO;}
recordState.currentPacket = 0;
recordState.recording = YES;
return YES;
```

ERROR is

```
Could not start Audio Queue
Error starting recording
```

please guide ...

Comment: Add the following code in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

    AVAudioSession * audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: nil];
    [audioSession setActive:YES error: nil];

Answer (score 1):

`@Kalaichelvan's` `comment` is `perfect`.

I was facing similar problem in `iOS 7.1`. Add following in `AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` :

```
AVAudioSession * audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance]; 
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: nil]; 
[audioSession setActive:YES error: nil];
```

**EDIT** : Above code is working for me